# How to override website_slides CSS?

Tags: odoo, odoo-13

I am using Odoo 13. I would like to change the background colour from purple to blue from a slide. `website_slides` is located in `/src/odoo/addons/website_slides`. I can't directly change `/src/odoo/addons/website_slides/static/src/scss/website_slides.scss`

I would like to override the following

```
.o_wslides_gradient {
    background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, #875A7B, darken(#875A7B, 10%));
}
```

This is my first time using Odoo. I would like to change the colour so that it is always blue instead of changing it per slide I use. How would I write a custom `module` and add it to `/src/user`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to inherit the [website.assets_frontend](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/addons/website_slides/views/assets.xml#L13) template to include the new `scss` file.

First, create a module (you can check the [Building a Module](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/reference/module.html) documentation), then:

- Add `website_slides` module to the manifest [depends](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/reference/module.html) list.
- Inherit the `website.assets_frontend` template like following:

  ```xml
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <odoo>

      <template id="assets_frontend" inherit_id="website.assets_frontend" name="Slides Frontend Assets">
          <xpath expr="//link[last()]" position="after">
              <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/scss" href="/MODULE_NAME/static/src/scss/website_slides.scss" t-ignore="true"/>
          </xpath>
      </template>

  </odoo>
  ```
- Create an `assets.xml` XML file and add to it the above code then add it to the `data` list in the manifest file.
- Create a `scss` file under `static/src/scss/website_slides.scss` and add the following scss code:

  ```css
  .o_wslides_gradient {
      background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, #7C7BAD, darken(#7C7BAD, 10%));
  }
  ```